# How to set the facebook default audience for the new oAuth 2 dialog

Tags: facebook

Googling for this i found out there *was* something called "advanced oauth setttings" in which you could set the default audience for your app (justme/friends/everyone) when the user connects your app. But it is nowhere to be found in the new version of the app settings pages in developer.facebook.com. When I connect to my app, it defaults to "friends". However there are other apps that default to "everybody". How is this done?

Also, looking at the getLoginUrl documentation, I see "scope" and "redirecturi" and some other settings, but here "default audience" is not available as well. (I am using the php-sdk)

```
return $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'email,offline_access,manage_pages,publish_actions',
  'redirect_uri' => $returnurl
));
```

Is it something that is not available any more? Or am i missing something.

Comment: You find it on the “Permissions” tab in your app settings. (While the permissions specified there are only for login through the app center, the _Default Activity Privacy_ however is for all logins.)

Comment: I can't find any "permissions" tabs in the app settings. This is the problem. They seem to have changed this.