# How to set default audience when Facebook App login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I make an Photo Sharing App on facebook; It's use #myAppSharing to search Photo people share by app. It's running now but I can't find any photo with hashtag #myAppSharing. Because when user login with FB Auth2.0, app ask permision; and set default audience to "Friend". So, I can't search #myAppSharing in public.

[image]

**How do I set default audience to "Public"?**

note: I use Javascript SDK like this:

```
FB.login(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        switch (response.status) {
            case 'connected':
                fbAuth = response;//save data                   
                state = new State('#upload');
                state.active();
                break;
            default:
                console.log('cannot connect Facebook account');
                break;
        }
    },{scope: 'email,publish_actions',display:'popup'});// <-- maybe set audience here or where?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research for hours, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459885/how-to-set-the-facebook-default-audience-for-the-new-oauth-2-dialog) with the same problem. Solution is setting up for app, answer base @CBroe:

> You find it on the “Permissions” tab in your app settings. (While the
>   permissions specified there are only for login through the app center,
>   the Default Activity Privacy however is for all logins.)

Thank @Broe so much!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the following js API [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.3) call:

```
FB.login(callback, {
    scope: 'publish_actions',
    default_audience: 'everyone'
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, I think the accepted answer is outdated.